# Why can't I add a bounty immediately for urgent questions?

Tags: discussion, bounty

If I have a question that needs a solution urgently - for example because it is blocking a release - why can't I put a bounty on it immediately after asking?

Comment: Because your failure in planning is of no interest to SO.

Comment: Something is badly wrong if you have an unsolvable problem blocking a release. And unfortunately, not a problem that can be answered by a single Stack Overflow question. "How did I get in this situation?" is something that can only be answered by you and your team.

Comment: `(...) a question that needs a solution urgently - for example because it is blocking a release (...)` The question is not blocking the release. Stack Overflow has nothing to do with whatever project you are working on.

Comment: See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/6506/248731. SE network sites are here for the "long tail" of providing value; if you need answers right now, hire a contractor.

Answer (score 16):

**A question's solution's urgency is completely irrelevant on SO.**

---

SO is meant to be a repository of good questions / answers.
The time frame in which these questions are answered doesn't matter.

If the OP of an question wants a *fast* answer, the OP should *hire* a professional.

Comment: Not to the person asking.

Comment: @sdgfsdh It is to everyone else though.

Comment: and to future visitors

Comment: The fact that it is irrelevant isn't a reason one way or another, this doesn't really answer anything. By this logic, why have bounties at all?

Comment: Bounties aren't meant for "urgent" questions. Urgency has nothing to do with bounties, @aw04.

Comment: Well, sure, but it doesn't really explain why there is a rule in the first place to wait 48 hours... the reason (urgent in this case) seems beside the point, unless it is literally to thwart people with urgent questions which seems odd

Comment: The rule is to prevent people from just "paying" with rep to get more views on low quality questions. There's a whole [meta SE question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57914/allow-bounty-immediately-or-at-least-before-48-hours) about that.

Comment: You cant "hire" one person to cover all the possible issues which may come about in a complex environment.  I for one agree with the OP. It would be hugely beneficial to be able to get urgent questions answered using some reward.

Comment: Theory and practice ... if this "meant to be" were true, several of the gamification aspects could well be tweaked so that the first question isn't usually the most prominent. Sure, sometimes it pans out and initial subpar answers will drop down when better answers "arrive" and sometimes votes will also even out over time. But for "fringe topics" I regularly see subpar answers being upvoted more than newer and better answers ...

Comment: @0xC0000022L: That's why you can downvote, too. But this discussion doen't really seem relevant to "urgency".

Comment: Is not bounty exist for "urgency"?

Comment: No. It's to draw extra attention to a question. It doesn't mean a question has to be answered ASAP.

Answer (score 3):

> Your poor planning does not constitute an emergency to me.

Think about why people answer questions on Stack Overflow. To a large extent because they can choose when and what. Sticking words like "urgent" or "I need this resolved by friday" does not produce any kind of positive response. If anything, it works exactly against its intended goal.

A bounty feature for that would do nothing.

Comment: Questions with bounties get more attention. They are more likely to be answered quickly. It would achieve the intended goal.

Comment: It would draw attention away from other good questions. Just because you're in a rush, doesn't mean your question is more important than others.

Comment: @sdgfsdh YOUR intended goal. Time is irrelevant on Stack's Qs &As. We write for future users. It's never about just you on this site. It's always about bettering Stack's library of high quality content. If you need this rush.... Chances are it's not a great question as you haven't had the chance to polish and refine it. Also,bountied questions are harder to close. If people could bounty right away it would become some kind of immunity from on hold/closure (or mods would get bothered a lot...)

Comment: @sdgfsdh The intended goal is to create long-term high quality Q/A. Wether that happens today or next week for any particular problem is entirely irrelevant.

Comment: This just seems like an argument against bounties in general.. but they already exist.